# Moto X 2nd gen. randomly goes into Priority Mode

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, moto-x

I own [Moto X 2nd gen.](http://www.motorola.in/Moto-X/Moto-x-gen2-india.html) and it goes into priority mode automatically. It is very annoying because the priority mode switches of my WiFi and reduces the phones ringtone volume.

[image: about phone]

<sup>About phone (click the image for its larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure that you're not activating it by accident? It is accessible via the volume buttons, so maybe you pressed the volume buttons by accident...

Comment: No, i have not activated it and not even from a volume buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Uninstall [Battery Doctor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ijinshan.kbatterydoctor_en)**

I figured out why this is happening. It's the Battery Doctor which turns off my Wifi and put my phone in priority mode.

I tested 3-4 times, when I enable (start) Battery Doctor, the issue was reproduced and when I forcefully stopped it, phone works properly.